# Suggestion of book or article about orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I was told to do a presentation in an ODE course on the topic: Periodic orbits for linear systems and stability. But they have not given me any reference, so I would be very grateful if you can help me with clear references on the subject. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you told us more about what level of course this is.

Comment: It is an undergraduate level course, for this reason I would like to read something that is basic and others of an intermediate level in order to develop as much as I can within my abilities.

Comment: Are the linear systems with constant coefficients, is a periodic forcing possible, that is something like $m\ddot x+c\dot x+kx=F\cos(\omega t)$?